# Countdown Timer is not working in magento 2.1.7?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, datetime

i am use date picker in system config and get date in this format **2015-07-15**
i want to convert it into this format **2015-07-15 17:29:31** because Jquery countdown is not work if i insert static value in **2015-07-15 17:29:31**this format then it will work. i have two date

1) countdown start date

2) countdown end date

i am use  **jquery.countdownTimer.js**

below is my count down script

```
<div id="countdowntimer" class="countdowntimer"><span id="future_date"></span></div>
 <script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Identixweb_Headernotification/js/jquery.countdownTimer'
    ], function ($) {
        console.log('countdowntimer start');
        jQuery("#future_date").countdowntimer({
            startDate : "<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); ?>",
            dateAndTime : "2017/09/22 08:26:55",
            size : "lg",
            regexpMatchFormat: "([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})",
//          regexpReplaceWith: "$1 days $2 hours $3 minutes $4 seconds REMAINING"        
            regexpReplaceWith: "$1<sup>days</sup> / $2<sup>hours</sup> / $3<sup>minutes</sup> / $4<sup>seconds</sup>"
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used custom countdown using jQuery,

Date Format

```
$test['date_from'] = 08/17/2017 2:52 PM 
$test['date_to'] = 08/26/2017 2:52 PM 
$microsecond=microtime();
$current_id=1;
```

Use this code its help you.

```
$startdate=strtotime($test['date_from']);
$enddate = strtotime($test['date_to']);
$interval = $enddate - $startdate;
$curr_time = strtotime(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'));

if($curr_time >= $startdate && $curr_time <= $enddate)
{
    $hours = abs($curr_time - $enddate)/(60*60);
    $time_diff = $hours * 3600;

    $html.='<ul ><li id="testdata-'.$current_id.'-'.$microsecond.'" class="testdata-contdown" ></li></ul>';
    $html.='<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($){
        var countDownDate = new Date("'.$test['date_to'].'").getTime();
        var x = setInterval(function() {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
            document.getElementById("testdata-'.$current_id.'-'.$microsecond.'").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the count down is over, write some text 
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
    </script>';

    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: i am make filed in system config and use datepicker for date field  and get system config value in block file and use it into phtml file.Above solution is for form field i am asking for system config if you know it plz share.

Comment: you just need to replace time ! other functionality is same here!

Comment: it works.......

Comment: @Bhavin Gehlot  i don't have time i only have date because datepicker save only date in system config.